# Problems refreshing access token

Tags: jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, scribe

I'm doing the `Google Calendar API` authentication using `Scribe`, that `OAuth 2.0`. The authentication is complete with success but I don't know how to save the  `accessToken` in the database. I'm using the following code:

```
Verifier verifier = new Verifier(code);
Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(EMPTY_TOKEN, verifier);
API_USER_TOKEN = accessToken.getToken();
API_USER_SECRET = accessToken.getSecret();
/*Guardar tudo na base de dados*/
saveToken(API_USER_TOKEN, API_USER_SECRET);
```

then, I need to retrieve the token e use it again, but how should I use the `accessToken` I stored in the database? How should I refresh it?

I'm attempting to refresh the token using the following code:

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST,"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token");
JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
request.addQuerystringParameter("grant_type", "refresh_token");
request.addQuerystringParameter("refresh_token", oldToken.getToken());
request.addQuerystringParameter("client_id", API_APP_KEY);
request.addQuerystringParameter("client_secret", API_APP_SECRET);
service.signRequest(oldToken, request);
Response response = request.send();
```

But I keep getting the same error: `invalid_grant bad request`

Comment: Its the refreshtoken you should be saving not the access token.

Comment: How should I be get it?

Comment: It is returned as part of the last part in the Authentication process.  This might help:  http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/ Sorry i cant help with Java

Comment: Check this link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline on refresh tokens.